# sqlite3 syntax error

Tags: iphone, syntax, sqlite

I am having some problem with sqlite.
I want to insert some data to database,however,when I use the function

`sqlite3_exec(db,sql,0,0,&zErrMsg);`,

the zErrMsg returns:

`near '\x90' syntax error`.

the code is :

```
(void) ExecuteCommand:(NSString *)command DBRef:(sqlite3 *)db
{
    const char *sql = [command UTF8String];    
    char *zErrMsg  = 0;

    sqlite3_exec(db,sql,0,0,&zErrMsg);    
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
}
```

I inserted some characters successfully before.  But when I try this time, I failed.  Does the problem due to the characters I use this time?

the sql statement is :

```
insert into b_1663 values(1,'1663','    \u7b2c1\u7ae0','\u9752\u86c7','    \u7b2c1\u7ae0

\u6211\u4eca\u5e74\u4e00\u5343\u4e09\u767e\u591a\u5c81\u3002

\u4f4f\u5728\u897f\u6e56\u4e00\u9053\u6865\u7684\u5e95\u4e0b\u3002\u8fd9\u6865\u53eb"\u65ad\u6865"\u3002\u4ece\u524d\u5b83\u4e0d\u53eb\u65ad\u6865\uff0c\u53eb\u6bb5\u5bb6\u6865\u3002

\u51ac\u5929\u3002\u6211\u5403\u9971\u4e86\uff0c\u5341\u5206\u6175\u5012\u5934\u5927\u7761\u3002\u7761\u5728\u8eab\u7554\u7684\u662f\u6211\u59ca\u59ca\u3002\u6211\u4eec\u76d8\u9519\u7ea0\u7f20\u7740\uff0c\u4e0d\u77e5\u4eba\u95f4\u4f55\u4e16\u3002

"\u8fd9\u662f\u9ad8\u4eba\uff01"

\u6211\u95ee\uff1a

"\u548c\u5c1a\u4e5f\u662f\u4eba\uff1f"

\u2014\u2014\u548c\u5c1a\u662f"\u4eba"\uff1f\u8fd9\u4e2a\u96c4\u4f1f\u505a\u5cb8\u7684\u548c\u5c1a\uff0c\u5e94\u8be5\u6bd4\u4eba\u9ad8\u660e\u70b9\u5427\uff1f

\u4ed6\u4e0a\u8def\u4e86\u3002

\u524d\u9762\u662f\u90a3\u8001\u548c\u5c1a\u3002 

');
```

the table structure:

```
create table b_1663(
   Num int primary key, 
   b_id varchar(20),
   b_sec_title varchar(50),
   b_name varchar(20),
   content text
);
```

Tell me if you know the answer.Thanks in advance!

Comment: You know, it would help an awful lot if we could see the actual statement you're trying to execute.

Comment: You still aren't showing us the SQL statement you're trying to execute.

Comment: We need to know what **sql** contains

Comment: I am inserting some chinese characters.

Comment: Are these so top secret that you can't show us your SQL statement or something? What's stopping you posting it?

Comment: Please show us the basic table structure.  It is hard to tell if you are trying to add a single row or multiple rows at the same time (only single row inserts are supported by sqlite3).

Comment: Any one can solve the problem?

Comment: I don't think those \uxxxx are UTF8 strings, Its looks utf16 to me, So, just wondering how can you inserting those into db.

Comment: sqlite3 supports utf-16, so it shouldn't be a problem in itself.

Comment: How can I encode my sql statement then,since I mainly want to insert Chinese characters into db?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:

You probably need to quote the string (i.e. replace characters that cause the parser to barf), or, better yet, use a parametrized query. Parametrized queries look something like:

```
sql="insert foo into bar values (?,?)"
sqlexec(sql, data)
```

Comment: If so, the error should get on first line `const char *sql = [command UTF8String];` not on zErrMsg.

Comment: when I create the table , it works ok, the zErrMsg is nil.
But when I insert something, it have syntax error.


 Does the problem due to the sql statement or the code?

Comment: syntax error? so you cannot compile at all or got exceptions?

Comment: If the zErMsg returns nil, it executes ok. If the zErMsg returns error, the db changes nothing.